# Using tee and paste results in a deadlock

Tags: pipe, tee, paste, mkfifo

I am trying to redirect stdout of a command into two "branches" using tee for separate processing. Finally I need to merge results of both "branches" using paste. I came up with the following code for the producer:

```bsh
mkfifo a.fifo b.fifo
python -c 'print(("0\t"+"1"*100+"\n")*10000)' > sample.txt
cat sample.txt | tee >(cut -f 1 > a.fifo) >(cut -f 2 > b.fifo) | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'
# outputs ~200 lines instantly
# and then ~200 more once I read from pipes
```

and then in a separate terminal I start the consumer:

```bsh
paste a.fifo b.fifo | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'
# outputs ~200 once producer is stopped with ctrl-C
```

The problem is that it hangs. This behaviour seems to depend on the input length:

1. If input lines are smaller (i.e. if second column contains 30 characters instead of 100) it works fine.
2. If `a.fifo` and `b.fifo` are fed with the same (or similar in length) input it looks like it also works fine.

The problem seemingly arises when I feed short chunks in say `a.fifo` and long in `b.fifo`. This behaviour does not depend on the order in which I specify pipes in `paste`.

I am not very familiar with Linux and its piping logic but it seems that somehow it deadlocks. My question is whether this can be reliably implemented somehow? If so, how? Maybe there are other ways without using `tee` and `paste`?

Comment: On my system, the producer script complains with `paste: /dev/fd/64: No such file or directory` due to using too many process substitutions on the second line. Removing one of the `{,}` bypasses this.

Comment: You also never flush the output buffer in `awk`. The output is flushed by printing a newline, or by calling `fflush()` in `awk`.  Your example is a bit contrived so it's difficult to say if this is your actual issue though.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I have edited the example so there are no `{,}` anymore. I am using `awk` to see how many lines it actually writes/reads. The behaviour does not change if `> /dev/null` or `| wc -l` is used instead of `| awk`.

Comment: Related: [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853)

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood the problem in detail. Obviously it is about the size difference of each line filling some buffer.

This can be "solved" by enlarging the buffer:

```
paste a.fifo <(buffer <b.fifo) | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'
```

Interesting fact: Adding a `buffer` to the generating command lets the `awk` finish but the consuming command still blocks (close to the end in my case):

```
$ cat sample.txt | tee >(cut -f 1 > a.fifo) >(cut -f 2 | buffer > b.fifo) | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}; END { print; print NR; }'
10001


$ paste a.fifo b.fifo | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}'
8152
```

Doesn't make sense IMHO. I would not be surprised if there is a bug involved.